# tcsh - echo escape code for escape

Tags: shell, escape-characters, tcsh

I am trying to programmatically create a file by printf-ing different things to it.  (i.e. `printf %s\\n hostname >> file.txt`)

I would like to send an Esc code  to clear the screen (it would be the first line).

In bash, I just use `printf $'\033[2J'$'\033[;H'` (`\033` being the octet for `Esc`) and it clears the screen.  Everything works as it should; as the first line in the file, when you `cat` the file, it clears the screen first.

In tcsh (the default shell for FreeBSD root), I can't seem to figure out how to "escape the escape" and get the equivalent of the bash escape codes.

I have been experimenting with (`printf` and `echo`)

- echo %{\e[2J]}
- echo \e
- echo \\e
- echo %{\033[2J}

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would be very appreciative!.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`printf` expands those in the format (first) argument by itself, no need for those `ksh93`-style `$'...'` quotes. So:

```
printf '\33[2J\33[H'
```

Note that `printf` is not a builtin in `tcsh`, so you'd be calling the `printf` command on the filesystem. You might as well call the `tput` or `clear` commands then, but in `tcsh` that's not needed as `tcsh` has built-in support for termcap/terminfo, so you can do:

```
echotc clear
```

That will query the terminfo or termcap database for the right escape sequence to send for the current terminal (according to `$TERM`) which is usually better than using a hard-coded one.

If you wanted to use `tcsh`'s `echo` built-in, you could do:

```
set echo_style = both # meant to be the default in tcsh
echo -n '\033[2J\033[H'
```

Or:

```
set echo_style = sysv # or both
echo '\033[2J\033[H\c'
```

Comment: This answered my question perfectly, but (trying not to ask another question in this topic)..I am curious by what you mean *printf is not built in to tcsh* because I have a virgin FreeBSD machine and `printf` works.

Comment: @Allan, compare `which echo` (or `which echotc`) vs `which printf` at the prompt of `tcsh`.

Comment: Understood.  I appreciate the help.